# Some user controls not loading when the 'Back' button is pressed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I'm working with ASP.NET and VB.NET.

I have a page which contains 5 user controls.
The page itself does nothing, it just presents the user controls to the user.

The user controls work fine when I come on the page, or when I refresh, but when I go to another page, and press 'Back' only two of my user controls shows up, and they don't work like they're supposed to!

Short description of the controls:

- 2 controls which look if the user has to create something and shows an option to do so. (goes to the DB)
- 2 controls show an overview if needed (goes to the DB)
- 1 control looks if the user is an admin (does not go to the DB, but looks in the securityContext)

So what happens is:

the first 3 controls don't show up
1 control shows his default state (although depending on the user it shouldn't)
the admin control always shows the admin link, even if the user isn't an admin

I've tried looking at caching (disabling, enabling), I've tried cheating the viewstate, I've tried using a placeholder, page_init, ..

Nothing seems to work though, and I'd like this to actually work, 'cause I'm pretty sure users will do this a lot. When I refresh everything works like it should again, because the server gets contacted again..

What should I do? :/

Some code:

```
<pm:MenuA ID="MenuA" runat="server" />
<pmm:MultiStepMenuA ID="MultiStepMenuA" runat="server" />
<rm:MenuB ID="MenuB" runat="server" />
<mm:MenuC ID="MenuC" runat="server" />
<br />
<am:AdminMenu ID="AdminMenu" runat="server" />
```

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** I don't have this problem with Firefox, only IE9 :/

Answer (score 1):

Blame internet explorer..

Apparently it kept on using an older version of my website "to improve speeds". I removed my history, and I unchecked the "Preserve favorite website data".

After that it worked. The older page was gone, and it was replaced by a newer version.

Thanks anyway, I hope this can help somebody else!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this problem is to add the following directive at the top of the page to prevent IE or IIS from caching this page:

```
<%@ OutputCache location="None" %>
```

You can apply this setting globally to all pages by adding the following to the system.web portion of your web.config:

```
  <caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" enableFragmentCache="false" omitVaryStar="true" />
  </caching>
```